# Hibernate query returns empty result list

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate, so there might be many problems, but I have an `Account` entity displayed here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 128)
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to select all accounts in the database in the following function:

```
public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Account a");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

The problem is that this returns an empty list, but when run the result sql (shown in the console by `<entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />`) in the Oracle SQL Developer editor, I do get results back.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I am trying to create a spring web app, so my connection an hibernate are configured in spring here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.checkpoint.core.repositories.jpa" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@[[url]]:[[port]]:[[sid]]" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.checkpoint.core.models.entities" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Setup transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.checkpoint.core.services.impl" />

</beans>
```

Comment: chage your query "select a from Account a" to "from Account"

Comment: @sumantipparapu That won't help - he is using the JPA entity manager with `JPQL` - not the Hibernate specific `HQL`

Comment: @Algosub How do you evaluate that the list is empty? How does the SQL look like? Did you check that you aren't using a different database from Hibernate? Do you use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` with `create`? From the information you gave it is difficult to tell where the problem is located.

Comment: You can try using: `Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Account a", Account.class);` This should solve the problem.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke , I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` with `validate`, and I check the returned list to make sure that it is indeed empty. Should I use `HQL`?

Comment: @anirbandebnath did not work :(

Comment: @Algosub: _How_ do you evaluate that the list is empty (show us the code). And please answer my other questions as well. And you don't need to use HQL.

Comment: Try to typecast the return value: `return (List<Account>) q.getResultList();`

Comment: @anirban How should a _cast_ change the _content_?

Comment: I agree @TobiasLiefke

Comment: @Algosub , Please share the other parts of code, where you are making the connections to the DB etc. There must be something missing somewhere. We can rectify that only after  you share the complete code.

Comment: @AnirbanDebnath Added the spring connection and hibernate configurations. Thanks!

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I see the result set in my app, but I also checked in the debugger and saw that the list size is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem,
I used the wrong `ojdbc` driver that did not support my exact `oracle` database version, so some things worked, and some didn't.

Thanks for all the help in comments!

Comment: How did you know what driver your db needed?

Comment: looked in the supported versions in the driver documentation

Comment: You need to know what database you're using before trying to look for a compatible driver. You can use SELECT * FROM V$VERSION to get the version and then google search for a driver and read documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the exact same issue with hibernate. For some tables, the generated Hibernate SQL query was not returning data back from DB in my service but when I ran it directly in my SQL Developer I got the data. For some tables, everything was working fine.
It turned out to be an issue with how I was inserting the data into the tables. I needed to write a **commit** statement explicitly after inserting the data.